# Regex to get the table with cell containing specific innerHTML

Tags: c#, regex

Image this table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr class="someclass">

<td>blah blah THISISIMPORTANT blah blah</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

I want to select only the tables that have TDs with the innerHTML that contains 'THISISIMPORTANT'.

This must be done with regular expressions in c#

this is what i have tried:

```
<table\s*.*?\s*>\s*.*?\s*<td\s*.*?\s*>\s*.*?\s*</td>\s*.*?\s*</table>
```

Comment: Why must it be done with Regex?

Comment: i edited the question and added what i have tried

Comment: dear @MaxDataSol if you know a better way other than regex I would be really glad.

Comment: `/<td>(?:.(?!</td>))*THISISIMPORTANT.*?<\/td>/`

Comment: You can use jquery and write your results in a hidden field that you can then read code behind

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: as i told i can't use any parser as the web hosting don't let me use any components

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Find a better web host. Seriously. If you can't drop a DLL in the `/bin` dir of your ASP.NET site, your web host is *useless*. No installation is necessary for .NET assemblies. Not allowing ANY assemblies will seriously hamper your ability to develop .NET apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/<table[^>]*>(?:.(?!<\/table>))*<td[^>]*>(?:.(?!<\/td>))*THISISIMPORTANT.*?<\/td>.*?<\/table>/
```

That's close... I mean, so long as no one uses a ">" inside a tag, you're fine.  But you really should find a better way to do it than regex.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)? It parses HTML really well and even supports LINQ, so it should be trivial to implement what you want with it.

You *could* parse the text you want with a regular expression, but then you'll need to assume will always be perfectly formed and in the same specific format, etc., which will make the code difficult to maintain.

EDIT : I found another question which is nearly identical to yours, with a code sample showing how to use HTML agility pack to implement a solution: [regex to get value of inside a particular TD in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876822/regex-to-get-value-of-inside-a-particular-td-in-html?rq=1)

Comment: I'm developing an asp.net page and i can't use any dll files (other than the .net framework itself) the web hosting forbided use of dll files

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Find a better web host. Seriously. If you can't drop a DLL in the `/bin` dir of your ASP.NET site, your web host is *useless*.